# Is There A Difference Between WAMP and MYSQL

Tags: mysql

This is my first post on Stack overlow
I'm a computer Engineer, but i'm relatively New to MYSQL
also i love using CLI

Backround info :
I Initially Installed MYSQL on my computer on IIS7 Virtual Server
Then Seperately installed PHP My Admin

when i did that it installed components such as MYSQL Workbench and Connectors and so on
i like the installed components but didn't use them frequently,
i only found myself using the Console and the Workbench
Now. the workbench has been replaced by PHP MyAdmin
at that time my database had only a few entries

after more research i learnt about WAMP, LAMP etc..

I'm now using the WAMP Stack

MY QUESTION IS THIS..
Other than the obvious fact that WAMP Uses Apache and i was using IIS7
is there any real difference between installing WAMP as a package
or installing all the components seperately

i would think not,  but, what i did notice before i installed WAMP, was that i was always having to alter directory locations to enable new features

i find in WAMP that i'm doing that so much

In Giving me an answer
i would like it to be considered that ..
- I'm pretty much doing standard Data entry
- Running Queries
- i would like to have the ability to Backup the data file locations without any issues
- i would like to have the ability to Import and Export a table to another table if i see fit
eg.
if i created a table in a database called (for example)    stock_my
and then i populated that with about 100 entries  for example

and then i  decided to rename the table     my_stock
i would like to be able to export the data from    stock_my  to a .sql file

and then to be able to Import the data to the new table

- Lastly , i would like Upgrading to newer versions of MySql or PHP My Admin to be relatively painless

THAT'S IT
SORRY ABOUT THE LONG POST

Any Comments are appreciated ahead of time
and i'd like to say , it's a pleasure to NOW be part of the community

sincerely

Martin Kuliza

Comment: WAMP is a prepackaged release of Apache, MySQL, PHP and related tools and is designed to run on Windows. That's it.

Comment: I don't get why people still use phpMyAdmin. Allow me to introduce you to the wonders of [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

Comment: I must admit i did Like MYSQL Workbench, Maybe i just didn't know how to use it properly.  So.. Here's a Question if i may..  considering i have WAMP, Would it mess things up if i installed MYSQL workBench,  is that do-able. i would like the flexibility, as i'm learning MYSQL to learn from PHP My Admin and workbench simultaneously and then make a decision as to which i prefer  (on last thing) considering i'm new to the forum,   is it ok to ask an additional question like this , on the fly, or .. should i have created another thread  Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is that Wamp installs those products already configured to work together and tuned up for a development environment, which means putting minimal footprint on your computer resources so you can work normally in the same machine you have the servers installed.

Installing them separately would only mean you would have to configure all that yourself, but essentually you would be installing the same things.

Comment: Thankyou, that's pretty much what i thought as well